# Allow specific domain to call api through nginx

Tags: nginx

In a nutshell, I have a website and an API both routed through Nginx. Is there any way to allow the API server response calls only from that specific website?

I am very novice in **serverfault** related things and this is my first question here.

Here are the details. I have a website, let's say **website.com**, developed with React-Redux which have the following Nginx config

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name website.com www.website.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain/pem/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey/pem/privkey.pem; 
}

server {
    if ($host = website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 
    if ($host = www.website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.website.com;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Form this **website.com** site I am calling an API which is also hosted in the same server but under a different domain, let's say **api.website.com**, which have the following Nginx config

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name api.website.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain/pem/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey/pem/privkey.pem; 
}

server {
    if ($host = api.website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.website.com;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

I want to know is there any way that I can change the config of **api.website.com** that allow only calls from **website.com**? The call is being intiated from frontend.

Answer (score 0):

If your `api.` website is really meant to be accessed by only a website on the same server, you can ensure that its domain resolves to the loopback interface, and deny non-local connections.

E.g. in `/etc/hosts`, put:

```
127.0.0.1 api.example.com
```

In NGINX config, have:

```
server {
    server_name api.example.com;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow ::1;
    deny all;
    ...
}
```

Now, when your main website talks to `api.example.com`, this will resolve
to `127.0.0.1`, which in turn ensures that the `api.example.com` will see the request coming from `127.0.0.1` as well. Requests to `api.example.com` which originate from the outside, will be denied.